# React dynamic render html

Tags: reactjs

I have this code here:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    {this.renderModal(this.state.isOpen)}
    <ReactGridLayout
      className="layout"
      layout={layout}
      draggableCancel="input,button"
      cols={12}
      rowHeight={30}
      width={1200}
    >
      <div style={gridItem} key={"0"}>
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal} id="0">
          Open the modal
        </button>
      </div>

      <div style={gridItem} key={"1"}>
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal} id="2">
          Open the modal
        </button>
      </div>

      <div style={gridItem} key={"3"}>
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal} id="3">
          Open the modal
        </button>
      </div>

    </ReactGridLayout>
  </div>
);
```

As you can see, this code is repeated three times.

```
<div style={gridItem} key={"0"}>
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal} id="0">
          Open the modal
        </button>
      </div>
```

Is there anyway I can do this dynamically? I want to be able to take in an integer variable then render as many of these as the variable. Hopefully I'm asking this correctly, I'm new to react.

Here is toggleModal in case it was necessary:

```
toggleModal = e => {
this.setState({
  isOpen: e.target.id
});
```

Comment: Create a separate component, within which you can `map` items from the array dynamically. And include that component within the `ReactGridLayout` by passing props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create another component with the render that you want inside, it'll look like this (the next code maybe not compile it's just a guide)

```
class toggle extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div style={this.props.gridItem}>
            <button onClick={this.toggleModal} id={this.props.id}>
                Open the modal
            </button>
        </div>
);
}
```

Between your render(){ end return, you should put this:

```
render() {    
 var rows = [];
   if(this.props.items){
     var num = this.props.items.length;
       for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
         rows.push(<toggle key={GetID()} gridItem={this.props.items[num]} id={i} />);
       }
   }
return (
...
```

And where you actually write each div you should write

```
<ReactGridLayout className=... @@stuff you have@@ ... >
    {rows}
</ReactGridLayout>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on where you said I should write
    {rows}
for each div?

Comment: @Zymptom Take a look, I think it's what you want.

Comment: @Zymptom You're welcome! if you could mark the answer as valid I'd really appreciate it :)